# Codeigniter - Restricting direct access to controller functions from URL call

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to know if there is any way through which I can restrict access to my controller functions through URL. But I want to give them a call through my link in the site. For example if I have a link in my site which points to a controller function:

```
<a href='test/function'>Call me</a>
```

But I don't want the controller function to be called when I place the above URL in my browser address bar. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: the ``<a>`` tag is doing exactly what you want to restrict

Comment: I didn't get you. I want the function to be called when I click "Call me" link. But when I paste the url "mysite/test/function" in my address bar, I don't want the function to be called.

Comment: What's the purpose? Are you loading some content via AJAX or something? Then I would recommend using something like a key which you can attach to a data-attribute.

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, I am loading via AJAX. What do you mean by a key and attribute attached?

Comment: If you use Ajax, hide the `href` of this `a` and set the URL in the js code.

Comment: @Sanks - this question doesn't make sense.. are you trying to get **CSRF** protection??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in the comment, that if you want to load the link via AJAX:

Your markup:

```
<a href="test/function" data-key="abc">
```

Your jquery:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var data = $(this).data('key');
    $('#result').load($(this).attr("href") + '?key=' + data);
});
```

Then in you CodeIgniter controller, you check to see if your key is present and matches ("abc"), else you return a 403 or something simillar.

Also, you could of course check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see where the user came from (this is however quite easily spoofed) and only allow access when the GET-request is made from your own site.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Apache and, consequently CodeIgniter, is allowing access to your PHP script to the outside world whether through a manually entered browser URL or through a visited hyperlink. Both scenarios connect to your web application in the exact same way, but they just *get there differently*.

You can allow access to only your CodeIgniter scripts (i.e. prevent public users from accessing a controller) by using:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

As Marcus has pointed out, you could use something like:

```
if (!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) $this->redirect('/home');
```

But it's often very inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: put this code at the beginning of every controller method

```
if (defined('BASEPATH') && !$this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Comment: Nice, but user can still alter the ajax request and do a mess if that function works globally. For example a global function to update, wich receive the name of table and other parameters that can be easily changed trough google developer tools. Did I got to far?

Answer (score 0):

This really helped. I also added this as an added check

```
$allowed_host = gethostname();
$host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
if(substr($host, 0 - strlen($allowed_host)) != $allowed_host)
  $this->redirect('/home');`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 In view: `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="back">`

 put inside your function in Controller: 


if(($this->input->post('back'))==1)
              {
                echo " what you want do here";
              }
              else
              {
                 $this->load->view('template',array('welcome_page')) ;
              }
```

form validation you will put inside this if condition..This will definitely work..