# The best way to secure PHP script on the server

Tags: php, security, server

What is the best (easiest but efficient) way to protect PHP script on the server to let anyone to run it? Anyone who gets the URL address of my script can run that script on my server which can cause unwanted (for me) operations. How can I solve this problem? If I gonna add at the beggining of my script condition like `if($pass == 'mySuperSecretPass') { ... }` then is no problem to read the code and get the right value for `$pass` variable.

Excuse my English language. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to use some kind of authentication and/or authorization mechanism, there are *many* examples available online.  Even the over-simplified example you gave (hard-coding a password) will do the job in simple enough scenarios.  Did you *try* using a password like that?  In what way did that attempt *not succeed*?

Comment: <?php 
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "") exit;
 ?> - Add to the top of your PHP pages

Comment: @LuckyChingi That hardly is a protection.

Comment: @arkascha what would you suggest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414768/codeigniter-restricting-direct-access-to-controller-functions-from-url-call#answer-14414859

Comment: @LuckyChingi If one needs an access control, then one should implement an access control. And not something that looks a bit like access control or something that is a bit access controlish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server should be the only one accessing the script using internal methods you can hide/block the file for everyone else using .htaccess rules.

```
RedirectMatch 404 "/(\/full\/path\/to\/restrictedFile\.php|\/path\/to\/restrictedFolder)"
```

This redirects everyone visiting /full/path/to/restrictedFile.php and /path/to/restrictedFolder to your error 404 page.
The script does not get opened at all.
The server does not respect .htaccess rules while accessing local files so the server can run it.

**For IIS :**

[This](http://lockmedown.com/when-should-you-return-404-instead-of-403-http-status-code/) is a page describing what i already answered but for IIS and not apache.

The general idea is this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="glimpse.axd">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
                <remove statusCode="403" />
                <error statusCode="403" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            </httpErrors>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I'm not used to working with IIS configurations and web.config files so i recommend you to read the page i linked to, you will probably know how to implement it.

Comment: I really like that - thank you. Is .htaccess available on Windows servers?

Comment: Works for me...
`<rule name="PHP redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="\.php$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url=" ... " redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>`

Comment: @JanChalupa if those servers use apache, yes. if you use IIS you must use a `web.config` file instead.

Comment: Am I still able to call these secured PHP scripts via AJAX? I thing I'm not.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the Apache .htaccess? (Note that you need to have AllowOverride enabled.)

It is possible to block access to certain URLs and password protect.

> ```
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Authentication Required"
> AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
> Require valid-user
> ```

To create the .htpasswd file, use this tool: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Also, you can blok IP's, and this tool:
http://www.htaccesstools.com/block-ips/

See if this helps: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, a very simple login with autologin feature. First I have a static login, in this case usr=username. I could also add a password or only accept a certain IP-address. I keep this in a file called login.php and include it in the necessary scripts.

If login is set set a cookie with username, valid 1 year. No need to log in every time from this computer!

If cookie exists, set session to logged_in=true

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['usr'] ) ) {
    if ( $_REQUEST['usr'] == 'username' ) {
        setcookie( 'usr', 'username', time() + 3600 * 24 * 730, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
    } else {
        setcookie( 'usr', '', time() - 3600 );
        unset( $_COOKIE['usr'] );
    }
}

if ( isset( $_COOKIE['usr'] ) && $_COOKIE['usr'] == 'username' ) {
    setcookie( 'usr', 'username', time() + 3600 * 24 * 730 );
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
}
```

Now, in my code I test for logged_in

```
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) {
    // Do some stuff
} else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' );
    exit;
}
```

If user is not logged in, redirect him to another page! I do not use any forms or stuff. The first time I access the page I do it like this: `http://www.myserver.com/?usr=username`

This is not maximum security, but a simple way to keep prying eyes out.

If you need a very secure login, forget about cookies and auto login and move to SSL encrypted server (https://).